# Disable flyway in Spring and tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, flyway

I have one of the older projects that is run using tomcat and I want to disable flyway. I used two versions: flyway.enabled=false and spring.flyway.enabled=false both in java project config file and config file in tomcat installation directory. None of that works for me. Other config properties work correctly. Does anybody has an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe it's overwritten in a application.resources outside the JAR or a env variable is set?

Comment: spring.flyway.enabled=false is working perfectly fine. As mentioned in previous comment either some environment specific file is overriding default config file or some env variable is conflicting

Comment: You are completely right, it was overwritten in business-config.xml file. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have already been answered in the comments but have you checked if any external configurations? Command-line arguments and external configuration with have priority over your internal config and could enable flyway if set even if your spring properties state otherwise.